# My output needs to be like this, it does not appear as I need it to be

Tags: python, printing

So I have to make the output like this for example:

```
Enter number of eggs: 19
1 dozen and 7 excess
```

instead it is showing up like this:

```
Enter number of eggs: 19
1 dozen
```

It does not show the excess

I tried this code:

```
eggs = int(input("Enter amount of eggs: "))

if eggs >= 1:
    dozens = eggs // 12
    excess = eggs % 12
    print ("dozens eggs {0}".format(dozens))
    print ("excess eggs {0}".format(excess))

else:
    print('Invalid Input')
```

but my professor requires me to have the exact output

```
eggs = int(input("Enter amount of eggs: "))

if eggs >= 1:
    dozens = eggs // 12
    excess = eggs % 12
    print ("dozens eggs {0} ".format(dozens))

elif eggs >= 1 == 0:
    print("{0} dozen and {1} excess".format(dozens, excess))

else:
    eggs = 0
    print("{0} excess".format(excess))
```

this is the current code

I expect the output to show: `1 dozen and 7 excess`. but it only shows the dozen

Comment: What do you intend `elif eggs >= 1 == 0:` to do?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it would show both the excess with the elif command, sorry I am new to python and programming overall

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually getting... Anyway it seems like you're complicating yourself too much... A simple `print("{} dozen and {} excess".format(dozens, excess))` should work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your `elif` statement should be called when your excess is greater than zero. I do not know what you intend by using the `eggs` variable in there. In addition, your `if/else` clause doesn't make much sense. You'll only enter the `else` clause if 0 eggs is input as the amount, so you would always print `0 excess`. But in reality, an error would be raised, because the excess variable is not defined at that point.

Comment: that code works! What if I needed to search for dozen without excess appearing in the output and excess without dozen appearing in the output? @Tomerikoo

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how and according to what condition, but in general just cut the expression to the part you want: just the dozen, or just the excess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the second piece of code? It should tell you there is a syntax error. Line 9: the "elif" must follow an "if". It cannot be at the start of a block of code.

And, "eggs >= 1 == 0" will always be False. For this to be True, it must satisfy "eggs > = 1 and 1 == 0". (I recommend using "and" in your code, it is clearer, especially for beginners.)

I don't seem to understand the point in an "elif". The "if" and "else" seems to account for all the possible cases. Eggs would either be greater than 0, or it's 0. 0 is a special case because it doesn't allow for division. (An "elif eggs < 0" would be of use, assuming the input might be negative.)

I think the following code should work (with minimum change to your code).
    eggs = int(input("Enter amount of eggs: "))

```
if eggs >= 1:
    dozens = eggs // 12
    excess = eggs % 12
    print ("{0} dozen eggs and {1} excess".format(dozens, excess))

else:
    excess = 0
    print("{0} excess".format(excess))
```

The following is what I would write, for your consideration (I'm a bit of a perfectionist):

```
eggs = int(input("Enter amount of eggs: "))

if eggs > 0:
    dozens = eggs // 12
    excess = eggs % 12

    if dozens == 0:
        print(excess, "excess")
    elif excess == 0:
        print(dozens, "dozen eggs")
    else:
        print ("{} dozen eggs and {} excess".format(dozens, excess))

elif eggs < 0:
    print("Amount can't be negative.")

else:
    print("0 excess")
```

Comment: this was exactly the code needed for the output I'm looking for. thank you for explaining it thoroughly, I have learned a lot from it. and to everyone else thank you for your patience with my stupidity